# Is this possible in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to allow people using my program to build up what amounts to several if conditions, which they will select from drop down lists.

```
First drop down : object
Second drop down : attribute
Third drop down : sign
Fourth drop down : amount
```

So the user's selection might look something like this;

```
person_a
age
>
18
```

Is it possible to build up an `if` condition in a string and then execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Ruby's [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005922) method. It allows you to evaluate a Ruby expression stored in a string, so you could build up an `if` statement from your menus and evaluate it using `eval`.

`eval` can be dangerous, especially when dealing with user input, but if you're careful it's one method you might be able to use.

Comment: I've done this in c# (despite that it's not a dynamic language).

Comment: Be very careful with `eval`. It's like giving a stranger your home keys and address

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have a method `find_person`, which takes the person's name and returns the person object, you can do

```
find_person(person_name).send(attribute).send(sign, amount)
```

Comment: This is a much better/more rubyish way than evaling a string.  We've got a rich object system and message passing for a reason.

Comment: No offense meant to mipadi, but this solution is so much better.